# How get Item from serialized list?

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, bundle

I sent data from adapter to fragment and get string like

MyMachine(id_mach=5, mach_mark=ПОН-4-40, picute_mach_link=https://agronaut.by/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/PON-4-40.png)

This string prited in Logcat, this is my code from Fragment class

```
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo, container, false)
    displayMessage = arguments?.getSerializable("mach_item") as Serializable
    Log.d("FFFFFFF", displayMessage.toString())
```

How can I extract data from serialized list? Thanks

Comment: `arguments?.getSerializable("mach_item") as? MyMachine` can you try that?

Comment: Yes, It's work, thanks

Comment: Welcome, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `getSerializable` method already gives you a `Serializable` so casting it to `Serializable` is redundant.
If the object you are adding on the extras implements `Serializable` then what you have to do is cast it to that object.

```
//considering your logs, I'm assuming the object is MyMachine
arguments?.getSerializable("mach_item") as? MyMachine
```